# switchButton isChecked(true/false) внутри itemView of recycleView. Room. Как создать условие а адаптере?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-room, recyclerviewadapter

Подскажите плиз, как сделать чтобы в зависимости от значения level в объекте Word в базе, switchButton внутри соответствующего itemView при загрузке активити заранее становился checked (в случае 200) или выключен (в случае 300)?

В адаптере:

```
private OnToggleChangeListener myListener;

public interface OnToggleChangeListener {
    void onToggleChange(Word word, boolean isChecked);
}

protected WordListAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word> diffCallback, OnToggleChangeListener listener) {
    super(diffCallback);
    myListener = listener;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    holder.btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {

        if (isChecked) {
            myListener.onToggleChange(currentWord, true);
            buttonView.setChecked(true);
            buttonView.setText("On");
        } else if (!isChecked) {
            myListener.onToggleChange(currentWord, false);
            buttonView.setChecked(false);
            buttonView.setText("Off");
        }
});
```

В MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onToggleChange(Word word, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked) {
        word.setLevel(200);
    } else {
        word.setLevel(300);
    }
    mWordViewModel.update(word);

}
```

Объект:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class Word {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    private int id;

    @NonNull
    private int level;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске активити (и не только) метод `onBindViewHolder` будет выполняться снова. Значит это отличное место для установки состояния, каких либо `view`. У вас уже есть установка состояния, НО только по нажатию на switchButton. Вам нужно выше установить состояние switchButton, не дожидаясь нажатия. Пример:

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    if (currentWord.level == 200) {
        buttonView.setChecked(true);
        buttonView.setText("On");
    } else {
        buttonView.setChecked(false);
        buttonView.setText("Off");
    }

    holder.btnSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {

        if (isChecked) {
            myListener.onToggleChange(currentWord, true);
            buttonView.setChecked(true);
            buttonView.setText("On");
        } else if (!isChecked) {
            myListener.onToggleChange(currentWord, false);
            buttonView.setChecked(false);
            buttonView.setText("Off");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только наверное в верхней части (где только условие для состояния при открытии) вместо buttonView.setChecked(true) ...... надо писать holder.btnSwitch.setChecked(true) и тд., верно?

Comment: @AlexRadionow да, вы правы, извините